# Show notification that value is max on arrow up click on input type="number"

Tags: javascript, html

I have **input:**

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="4" />
```

How can I display alert that max value is 4 when user clicks on up arrow and current value is already 4?

Comment: Try adding the attribute, `<input onclick = "function() { if (Number(this.value) >= 4) {alert("Max value is 4" ) } }">`

Comment: @edddd Does not work in browsers that respect the max=4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

You have to tell the field it was already clicked and reached 4 before alerting next time

Browser that respect the max=4 will not allow the field to increment beyond 4 so the value on its own is not enough

```js
document.getElementById("num").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const value = this.value,
    max = this.getAttribute("max"),
    min = this.getAttribute("min"),
    minned = this.dataset.minned === "true";
  maxed = this.dataset.maxed === "true";
  if (value === max && maxed) {
    alert("Value is max");
  }
  if (value === min && minned) {
    alert("Value is at 0");
  }
  this.dataset.maxed = value === max ? "true" : "false";
  this.dataset.minned = value === min ? "true" : "false";
})

document.getElementById("num").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const value = this.value || 0,
    min = this.getAttribute("min"),
    max = this.getAttribute("max");
  if (value != "" && value > max || value < min) {
    alert(`Value should be between ${min} and ${max}`);
    this.value = "";
  }
  this.dataset.maxed = value === max ? "true" : "false";
  this.dataset.minned = value === min ? "true" : "false";
})
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="4" />
```

Comment: suggestion : validating when the user inputs a number manually because later i can click the up anytime without any alert

Comment: Also , click is not a suitable option because when the number is 4 & clicking on the input field will also trigger the alert

Comment: @SandrinJoy I cannot handle click any other way. I added test for pasting now too

Comment: I think I could wrap them into one function and testing event.type

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function handleMyInput(event){
  const { value, max } = event.target
  if(value >= max) alert('Max value reached');
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="4" id='myInput' onclick='handleMyInput(event)' />
```

Comment: That alerts when hitting 4 and not after trying to increment again after already at 4

Comment: Still does not work as requested. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63921128/295783) to see how

Comment: yes, your approach looks ideal for that requirement. Good, mine works as soon as the max value is reached

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess from your information adding an eventlistener would do what you want to:

```js
const input_number = document.getElementById("input_number");
input_number.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if(input_number.value > 4) {
    alert("Max. number is 4!")
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="input_number" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="4" />
```

Comment: Your code does not work in browsers that respecct the max=4